# How to de-slugify a request URL before the action is executed in Play! Framework

Tags: parameters, playframework, request, slug

I'm always slugyfing my links, so that for example:

```
http://site.com/this%20is%20a%20link
```

becomes:

```
http://site.com/this-is-a-link
```

I would like to de-slugify the request URL before any action is processed, so that for example if I have the following route configured:

```
GET /{parameter}   Controller.action
```

And I invoke a slugyfied link like:

```
/this-is-a-link
```

The `parameter` is processed as `"this is a link"` instead of `"this-is-a-link"`.

Any tips?

EDIT: Maybe the replacement of the values must be done before the `Router` actually routes the request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slugs are meant to be saved in the database along with what they point to. Creating a slug is a one-way transformation. There is no such thing as "de-slugify" as multiple characters get translated into the same character.

You should handle possible collisions by adding a number suffix or something similar.